# PHP Composer custom installer

Tags: php, json, composer-php

I'm trying to address this issue now for a long time but still could not figure out what's my mistake.

I've got two repositories I want to combine. The Application and the Framework Core.

```
// Application
 - composer.json
 - public/
 - CCF/
   - core/ <- here the core package should go 
   - vendor/ <- here it goes instead
```

Now basically I want to create a composer package that install's into `CCF/core/` instead of `CCF/vendor/clancats/core/etc..`

So I created a custom installer at:

`vendor/composer/installers/src/Composer/Installers/ClanCatsFrameworkInstaller.php`

```
class ClanCatsFrameworkInstaller extends BaseInstaller
{
    protected $locations = array(
        'core'      => 'CCF/core/',
        'orbit'     => 'CCF/orbit/{$name}/',
    );
}
```

**The composer.json of the core**

```
{
    "name": "clancats/core",
    "description": "The ClanCatsFramework Core repository",
    "type": "clancatsframework-core",
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3",
        "composer/installers": "~1.0"
    }
}
```

**composer.json of the application that should implement the core at CCF/core**

```
{

    "type": "project",  
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3",
        "clancats/core": "dev-master"
    },
    "config": {
        "vendor-dir": "CCF/vendor"
    },
}
```

But after all that composer still installs the core package at /vendor/clancats/etc..

So my question is what is my mistake that composer won't install the core package to CCF/core/?

- Added composer/installers to the requires.
- I created a custom installer which defines the path to the core
- Set the type of the core package to my custom one.

Another question that is spinning around my head, is my pattern wrong? I mean did i misunderstand how to use composer?

Github:

- framework install repo: https://github.com/ClanCats/Framework
- core repo: https://github.com/ClanCats/Core

Thanks for your help guys :)

Comment: Please add the following: Describe what you are trying to do, what you expect the result to be, and what you get instead (and if it isn't obvious, what kind of difference between expectation and reality bothers you). These are the basic informations needed to get help - as it stands right now, you are simply stating that you do something, and that you need help, but you have not asked at least one question.

Comment: @Sven Thanks for your reply. I updated the question hopefully it's now more clear what im asking for.

Comment: Great update! Now anyone might be able to help. You even get some points from me. :)

Comment: Why can't you leave them in the vendor dir?

Comment: @PatrickForget The core i could and i already did. But at least the orbit packages 'CCF/orbit/{$name}/' should have their own install directory.

Comment: It sounds like you want the core package to define where it will live inside the parent project? I think this is a little unusual because if more components did this then they would not be as resusable (we would have to structure our projects according to the dependencies). Would you be happy to just specify the installer path for that core component inside the composer.json of the parent project? https://getcomposer.org/doc/faqs/how-do-i-install-a-package-to-a-custom-path-for-my-framework.md

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So for everyone who runs into the same problem:

My mistake was that i didn't require the `composer/installers` in the main repository.

**The composer installers have to be required in both repositories.**

So in this case:

```
{
    "type": "project",  
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3",
        "clancats/core": "dev-master",
        "composer/installers": "~1.0"
    },
    "config": {
        "vendor-dir": "CCF/vendor"
    },
}
```

solves the problem.